# Sharing files with Windows CE virtual machine in Virtual PC?

Tags: windows-ce, virtual-machine, share, virtual-pc

How can I share a file with my virtualised Windows CE box if the [HPC Factor WindowsCE Virtual PC images](http://www.hpcfactor.com/support/cesd/s/0119.asp) do not support the Virtual Machine Additions *or* the virtual network driver?

I cannot mount a shared folder, since it requires the VM Additions and I cannot copy a file via the network, since it requires a working network driver.

Is there a way to copy a file from my host system to my CE VM or is there a better way to emulate Windows CE on my Windows 7 host system?

Answer (score 0):

If your OS image includes ActiveSync, you could try to install a virtual (software-based) serial port, and connect ActiveSync on your workstation with the one on your virtual device. I have not tested this myself in Windows CE but in theory it should work. I found a commercial virtual serial port software [here](http://www.mks.zp.ua/vspdxp.php), and an open source one [here](http://com0com.sourceforge.net).
If your OS image does not support ActiveSync, you could still try this approach using two serial port-based file transfer applications, for example hyperterminal on your workstation and [Zterm CE](http://www.tsreader.com/ztermce/index.html) on Windows CE.